clip two image in the same graph
I would like to clip image a with a (200,100) rectangle as imageA1, and clip another image b with a (100,100) rectangle as imageB1. then put imageB1 below imageA1, and scale imageB1 width to the same width as imageA1 and keep imageB1 ratio.
Current code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% scope1
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
    \clip (50pt,-150pt) rectangle (250pt,-250pt);
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {
      \includegraphics[width=500pt]{example-image-a}
    };
\end{scope}    
%scope2
\begin{scope}[shift={(scope1.south west)}]
    \clip (200pt,-150pt) rectangle (300pt,-250pt);
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {
      \includegraphics[width=500pt]{example-image-b}
    };    
\end{scope}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Expected:

Scale imageB1 to imageA1's width.
Remove the blank area between imageA1 and imageB1.

Results:

Expected results:


I can see why you may want 1 and 2, but I'm less clear why you expect them. don't you get exactly what you'd expect here? you've put the original images one on top of the other. you've then clipped everything except a 200pt by 100pt rectangle in the middle of the top one and a 100pt by 100pt square in the middle of the bottom one. so obviously what's visible will be less of B than A and somewhat lower down.

it seems to me what you really want to do is to clip/trim/crop the images so the nodes are not the original image sizes, but that's not what your code does.

@lucky Can you add a sketch how the result should look like?

Note that this solution works with pdfTeX. \includegraphics does NOT work correctly with the options used on luaTeX.
The code below includes three pictures. The first illustrates what your original code does. The second and third illustrate one way to achieve two guesses as to what you wanted that code to do.
Current code
As is, what your code basically does is place the scaled images and then clip the result, which means most of the image becomes white space. To see the effect, we can replace \clip by \draw [red]. We then use the backgrounds library to put the images below the drawn boxes. (This was just to keep the order the same as in your question.)
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
    % \clip (50pt,-150pt) rectangle (250pt,-250pt);
    \draw [red] (50pt,-150pt) rectangle (250pt,-250pt);
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {%
        \includegraphics[width=500pt]{example-image-a}%
      };
    }
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(scope1.south west)}]
    % \clip (200pt,-150pt) rectangle (300pt,-250pt);
    \draw [red] (200pt,-150pt) rectangle (300pt,-250pt);
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {%
        \includegraphics[width=500pt]{example-image-b}%
      };
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


This is actually what we should expect. \clip clips whatever follows, but this happens after the nodes' contents are set. What we want to do instead is to clip the contents of the nodes and then align them.
A method to clip and scale before aligning
We provide a new command

\IncludeGraphicsViewport[<options for \includegraphics>]{<x coord of lower left in bp relative to origin of image's bounding box>}{<y coord of lower left>}{<x coord of upper right>}{<y coord of upper right>}{<filename>}
coordinates may be any valid floating point expression (in the sense of \fpeval).

Figuring out the coordinates makes this a bit trickier given your specification in terms of pts relative to the scaled images. At least, I think this is what you were doing? But I'm not sure because you also expected them to be the same width. But if the specs were relative to the original images, I think you'd also say you expected different parts of those images to be included. So this isn't very clear. If you wanted something slightly different, the specs should be easy to adjust to meet the requirement.
To make this easier, we set up a couple of factors. Only one of these is used in the code below, but you might want to other if I guessed wrong.

\edef\luckyfactor{500/321.2} is not used, but can be used to scale up from the original image to the scaled version. Since you're presumably using a different image, replace 321.2 by the width in points of your actual image.
\edef\luckyfactori{321.2/(500*1.00374)} scales down from values specified for the scaled image to the equivalent values for the original. This also demonstrates how to convert from points to the 'big points' we need to specify viewport for \includegraphics. That is, in your document 1bp is equivalent to 1.00374pt.

Guess 1
This allows us to say, for example,
\IncludeGraphicsViewport[width=500pt]{\luckyfactori*50}{240.9-150*\luckyfactori}{\luckyfactori*250}{240.9-250*\luckyfactori}{example-image-a}%

This clips example-image-a to the region shown by the red rectangle in the image above. Similarly,
\IncludeGraphicsViewport[width=500pt]{\luckyfactori*200}{240.9-150*\luckyfactori}{\luckyfactori*300}{240.9-250*\luckyfactori}{example-image-b}%

clips example-image-b to the region shown by the red square.
So we can say, for example,
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724423/
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
    \path  (50pt,-150pt) rectangle (250pt,-250pt);
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {%
        \IncludeGraphicsViewport[width=500pt]{\luckyfactori*50}{240.9-150*\luckyfactori}{\luckyfactori*250}{240.9-250*\luckyfactori}{example-image-a}%
      };
    }
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(scope1.south west)}]
    \path (200pt,-150pt) rectangle (300pt,-250pt);
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {%
        \IncludeGraphicsViewport[width=500pt]{\luckyfactori*200}{240.9-150*\luckyfactori}{\luckyfactori*300}{240.9-250*\luckyfactori}{example-image-b}%
      };
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

to produce

Guess 2
If you actually wanted the lower image to be square, as your question suggests, you can replace
\IncludeGraphicsViewport[width=500pt]{\luckyfactori*200}{240.9-150*\luckyfactori}{\luckyfactori*300}{240.9-250*\luckyfactori}{example-image-b}%

by
\IncludeGraphicsViewport[width=500pt,height=500pt]{\luckyfactori*200}{240.9-150*\luckyfactori}{\luckyfactori*300}{240.9-250*\luckyfactori}{example-image-b}%

In general, you shouldn't specify both width and height as it will distort the image, but this is not the general case.

Complete code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724423/
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
% 321.2x240.9 pt (orig img dims)
\edef\luckyfactor{500/321.2} % 1.5567 (4dp)
\edef\luckyfactori{321.2/(500*1.00374)}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \lucky_includegraphics:nnn
{
  \includegraphics[#1,viewport=#2,clip]{#3}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \lucky_includegraphics:nnn { nen }
\NewDocumentCommand \IncludeGraphicsViewport { O {} mmmmm }
{
  \lucky_includegraphics:nen {#1} { \fp_to_int:n {#2} ~ \fp_to_int:n {#3} ~ \fp_to_int:n {#4} ~ \fp_to_int:n {#5} } {#6}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
    % \clip (50pt,-150pt) rectangle (250pt,-250pt);
    \draw [red] (50pt,-150pt) rectangle (250pt,-250pt);
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {%
        \includegraphics[width=500pt]{example-image-a}%
      };
    }
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(scope1.south west)}]
    % \clip (200pt,-150pt) rectangle (300pt,-250pt);
    \draw [red] (200pt,-150pt) rectangle (300pt,-250pt);
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {%
        \includegraphics[width=500pt]{example-image-b}%
      };
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
    \path  (50pt,-150pt) rectangle (250pt,-250pt);
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {%
        \IncludeGraphicsViewport[width=500pt]{\luckyfactori*50}{240.9-150*\luckyfactori}{\luckyfactori*250}{240.9-250*\luckyfactori}{example-image-a}%
      };
    }
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(scope1.south west)}]
    \path (200pt,-150pt) rectangle (300pt,-250pt);
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {%
        \IncludeGraphicsViewport[width=500pt]{\luckyfactori*200}{240.9-150*\luckyfactori}{\luckyfactori*300}{240.9-250*\luckyfactori}{example-image-b}%
      };
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
    \path  (50pt,-150pt) rectangle (250pt,-250pt);
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {%
        \IncludeGraphicsViewport[width=500pt]{\luckyfactori*50}{240.9-150*\luckyfactori}{\luckyfactori*250}{240.9-250*\luckyfactori}{example-image-a}%
      };
    }
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(scope1.south west)}]
    \path (200pt,-150pt) rectangle (300pt,-250pt);
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {%
        \IncludeGraphicsViewport[width=500pt,height=500pt]{\luckyfactori*200}{240.9-150*\luckyfactori}{\luckyfactori*300}{240.9-250*\luckyfactori}{example-image-b}%
      };
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Further variations
If you actually meant the clipping path to apply to the unscaled images, you could use
\IncludeGraphicsViewport[width=500pt]{50}{240.9-150}{250}{240.9-250}{example-image-a}%

and
\IncludeGraphicsViewport[width=1000pt]{200}{240.9-150}{\luckyfactori*300}{240.9-250}{example-image-b}%

Or perhaps you'd want to set the widths to \luckyfactor*500pt and \luckyfactor*1000pt in that case?

I think there is something wrong with this and it shouldn't be done like this.

Awesome,  Can we use coordinate from top left to right bottom? current implementation looks like from bottom left to top, then I can (0,0,50,50) to crop the top left square.

@lucky1928 (0,0) is the origin specified by the included image. all of these \includegraphics options are basically glosses over multiply realised functionality which varies according to image type, engine and driver. what you're specifying are coordinates relative to the origin the image specifies. so you could fairly easily write a command which took myviewport=a b c d and fed viewport=a d c b to \includegraphics. that's just \newcommand or \NewDocumentCommand or whatever. but each of a, b, c & d would still be measured from the image's origin. (here, from bottom left.)

Thanks, is it possible to detect image width/height with code? user input is rectangle then get the clipped image.

@lucky1928 put it in a box and measure height/depth/width of the box? you can get it directly, but that's engine-dependent, so boxing it is probably safer. but the other answer is probably better. I don't think this one works.

This uses the clip features built into graphics and adjustbox.  I avoid clipping and scaling at the same time, since I don't know which is done first.
In this case the result is slightly more complicated, but mostly due to the use of anchor=north west which meant adding the (unknown) height to the vertical clip coordinates.
I wasn't sure if you wanted the images side by side or corner to corner, so I provided both options.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[width=500pt]{example-image-a}}%
\dimen1=\dimexpr \ht\tempbox-150pt\relax
\dimen3=\dimexpr \ht\tempbox-250pt\relax
\adjustbox{clip=true,viewport=50pt \dimen3 250pt \dimen1}{\usebox\tempbox}%
\savebox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[width=500pt]{example-image-b}}%
%\dimen1=\dimexpr \ht\tempbox-150pt\relax% unchanged
%\dimen3=\dimexpr \ht\tempbox-250pt\relax% unchanged
\resizebox{200pt}{\height}{\adjustbox{clip=true,viewport=200pt \dimen3 300pt \dimen1}{\usebox\tempbox}}
%\raisebox{-\height}{\resizebox{200pt}{\height}{\adjustbox{clip=true,viewport=200pt \dimen3 300pt \dimen1}{\usebox\tempbox}}}

\end{document}


much tidier than mine. you might want to add that this works with luatex :-). however, I can't get the corner-to-corner case to compile.

Sorry about that.  I didn't notice the error message.
